# Multitier Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

May i know what is the purpose of this ff project name. And what is the difference in business rules, business objects, and business logic. 
ProjectName.BusinessLogic
ProjectName.DataAccess
ProjectName.Common
ProjectName.Enum
ProjectName.Model

Comment: That is layered architecture, these are all different layers of the project. DataAccess would contain all your database access code, Enums are hard coded values available in project used mainly for dropdowns or radioboxes, Model would contain all your classes which map to your database tables. I am not sure about Common, maybe its a common service layer. Business Logic/business rules layer would contain all your business rules (you would make all checks to your objects here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you read on how to ask a good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first

Straight from [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns):

> design principle for separating a computer program into distinct
>   sections, such that each section addresses a separate concern.

I hope that you are not the developer taking over this project, because it seems like you have minimal programming basics. That being said, design principles are not hard and fast rules, it's a recommended set of design & pattern for plenty of reasons (not going to lose focus of this particular question, you can search for them easily)